# How to follow OpenBSD current?

Tags: openbsd

We want to try out OpenBSD on desktop, but using the -current flavor:

https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#Flavors

```
-current: The -current branch is where active development work is done.
Every six months, -current is tagged and becomes the next-release.
```

Where can I download the installer ISO for this flavor and how do I keep the installed `-current` flavor up-to-date?

pkg_add handles ports, but this is about the main OS, so it must be something else with we can update the binary files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the snapshot for your platform and install it. When you want to update the base, download the file `bsd.rd` from the snapshot directory in the mirror, copy it to `/` and reboot. Run `boot bsd.rd` in the boot loader prompt and reply `u` in the question which the installer asks you. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have stable installed, you can change to current with the following instructions:

1. `doas ftp -o /bsd.rd https://cloudflare.cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/amd64/bsd.rd`
2. Reboot your machine with `doas reboot`
3. Type: `boot bsd.rd` at bootloader prompt
4. Select U(Upgrade) at first prompt question
5. After upgrading everything and after rebooting again, type: `doas pkg_add -u` to get all the most recent updates since your installation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're installing from scratch, instead of installing -stable , you can just download [the snapshot installXX.iso](http://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/amd64/install64.iso) for your arch and install as usual.

Once in a while you'll need to upgrade to the actual -current. While you can use the bsd.rd method or the manual one (extracting the sets - like for a remote machine you don't have console access), there is now [sysupgrade(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/sysupgrade), an official tool for upgrades that handles -current too.

Anyhow, following [current.html](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/current.html) is quite mandatory, and be sure to always upgrade from stable to current from a snapshot (not compiling from source) as stated in said page.